# Multiplicar elementos de un Array

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Estoy creando una función que reciba un array de números y los multiplique pero no he dado con una solución viable.

Esto es lo que he conseguido hasta ahora:

```js
var total = 0;

var producto = [1,4,7];

function productoria(){
  for (var f=0;f<producto.lenght;f++){
    if(producto[f]!=0){
      total = total + (producto[f]*total);
    }
  }return total;
}
console.log(productoria());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tienes 3 errores:

1. Tienes un typo en `length`
2. Necesitas inicializar la variable `total` a 1
3. No necesitas sumar el total en cada iteracion

Quedaria asi:

```js
var total = 1;

var producto = [1,4,7];

function productoria(){
  for (var f=0;f<producto.length;f++){
    if(producto[f]!=0){
      total = (producto[f]*total);
    }
  }return total;
}
console.log(productoria());
```

Comment: Vale, pero que errores de principiante he tenido. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Oh,¿ y si quisiera parametrizar la función con el array?

es decir, que dentro de productoria() se ingresen varios valores sin tener que cargar un array yo

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo puedes editar tu pregunta indicando lo que requieres.

Answer (score 10):

Usando `reduce()` es realmente corto:

```js
const producto = [1,4,7];

const res = producto.reduce((p,c)=>p*c);

console.log(res);
```

La documentación de MDN con ejemplos [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce). 
Básicamnete reduce funcionaría así:

```
arr.reduce(callback(acumulador, valorActual), valorInicial)
```

En donde el `acumulador` almacena los valores que queremos que guarde cuando queremos que los guarde. El `valorInicial`, si no lo especificamos, toma el primer valor del array (en este ejemplo: 1). En el caso de la multiplicación, cada iteración estamos multiplicando al `acumulador` el valor de cada elemento, funcionaría como la variable `total` de la pregunta. El ejémplo sin usar la función flecha y usando el `return`, sería:

```js
const producto = [1, 4, 7];

const res = producto.reduce(function (acumulador, valorActual){
    acumulador = acumulador * valorActual;
    return acumulador;
} );

console.log(res);
```

La función flecha nos permite omitir el `return` y las `{}`.
En este caso, el valor final es un solo número, pero podríamos definir como valor inicial un objeto o un array y operar sobre el `acumulador` como lo haríamos con un objeto o un array.

Comment: Tu respuesta luce muy lógica y simple, elimino la mia y te doy el espacio +1

Comment: Muy interesante respuesta, no estaría demás una explicación de por que funciona.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, es muy práctica

Answer (score 7):

La productoria es la multiplicación de todos los elementos del array, por tanto no hace falta realizar una suma, luego el resultado se multiplica a partir de 1.

Otra forma de obtener la productoria de un array es con un método recursivo:

```js
var producto = [1,4,7];

function productoria(f){
  return f<producto.length ? producto[f]*productoria(f+1) : 1;
}

console.log(productoria(0));
```

El código así es mucho mas simplificado.

Espero haber contribuido a resolver el problema, saludos.

Answer (score 4):

En caso que no quieras multiplicar por el numero 0, te dejo una solucion:

```js
const producto = [1,4,7,0];


let res = producto.filter(data => data !=0)
    .reduce((e, f) => e * f)



console.log(res);
```

use `filter` por que en tu pregunta pusiste una condicion if que ningun numero sea igual a 0  ->   `if(producto[f]!=0){`

Comment: en dicho caso no sería necesario el `.filter()`, se podría hacer: `let res = producto.reduce((e, f) => f ? e * f : e);`

Comment: @Emeeus mmm si tambien es otra forma gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

let myArray = [1, 2, 5, 77, 99, 7, 6, 9]

let multiplicaciom = myArray.reduce((a, b)=> a * b)
console.log(multiplicaciom)

Comment: Podrías explicar ¿en qué difiere tu respuesta a la ya plublicada por el compañero Emeeus? aparte del uso de funciones flecha, claro. Recuerda que no solo es responder por responder sino que tienes que respaldar tu respuesta, de este modo ayudas a futuros visitantes. Te invito a leer [answer].

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).